# PHP: What is the best practice to generate a page display from a delimited txt file?

Tags: php

I have this large txt file 8mb+ that is delimited and I need to take this file's content and generate a page to display it which needs to include pagination and more detailed info.  This file gets updated constantly so I can't just import this file into a database each time.  So my question is what is the best practice to do something like this?

My ideal solution is to display a listing of summary information and if they click on "more details", it will just display a more detailed page.  Can this be done dynamically like what I described?

Thanks...

Comment: Yeah if no one has a good way of doing this, then I guess I have to store it in db...So I am guessing no body does this since the file is too large?

Comment: Ok, it is becoming clear now that this should be handled in a database...Please submit your answer so I can accept it...thanks.

Comment: Does the file only get appended to, or are existing rows sometimes changed or removed?  In the former case, you _could_ try using byte offsets to efficiently access rows in the file, although I wouldn't really recommend this technique unless you know what you're doing and you're sure there's no better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you don't want to parse an 8mb file at each page load (*you don't*), I'd recommend storing the delimited data in database table rows and access the information that way. If possible, instead of having the text file constantly updated, provide an interface to update the database instead and cut out the middle man.

Paginating a text file like you mention can be a nightmare. Using built-in filestream functions like `fseek` are only useful if your rows are all exactly the same byte-length (which might be the case). Using a database you can easily access (for example) the last twenty rows without needing to load up the entire data set. A text file just isn't conducive to what you're trying to do.

It sounds like your delimited file is created from some other software and this precludes you from storing the data directly into a database. In this case I would write a script that checks the text file periodically for changes and stores new information into your database as it appears in the text file. If it's acceptable to allow the php script to modify the delimited file you could then delete rows as they're stored in the database to keep the text file size small.

A database, though, is the best solution to achieve the type of scenario you outline.

Comment: Actually, to read the last 1 kB of a file you can just use [`fseek`](http://php.net/fseek). What's difficult with flat files is finding some specific line somewhere in the middle, especially if you don't know the exact byte offset for it.

Comment: Yes. You could use `fseek` if the text file has entries with fixed length or if it just gets new entries appended to the existing ones (in that case, one could have a file containing the positions and lengths of each entry). But if random entries inside the file are updated, it's not so easy.

Comment: I considered `fseek`, but to actually paginate the results `fseek` probably won't be of much help. How likely is it that the rows are of identical byte-length to be able to seek directly to the location necessary? I guess it's possible, but still is not the "best practice" the OP asked for.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen It's my understanding that even with `fseek` you still have to load the entire file into memory to perform the seek operation. Is that not correct?

Comment: No, `fseek` just moves a low-level filesystem cursor around the file, it doesn't need to read _any_ of the file into memory.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the info, will update the answer to avoid confusing people.